# Think Python Exercise 5.2, Check Fermat

Tags: python

The user is asked to input a, b, c, and n. n must be greater than 2, so I am checking for that in checkn(). There's probably a far simpler method in doing this; if there is please let me know!

Traceback says "Error: name 'n' is not defined'. I am assuming I am having some confusion with local and global variables but I am unsure of how to get around this mistake of mine.

What am I misunderstanding?

Here is my code:

```
import math

def fermat():
    if (a**n) + (b**n) == (c**n):
        print('Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!')
    else:
        print("No, that doesn't work")

def checkn():
    print('insert n, must be greater than 2')
    n = int(input())
    if n <= 2:
        print('n must be greater than 2')
        checkn()
    else:
        fermat()

a = int(input('input a\n'))
b = int(input('input b\n'))
c = int(input('input c\n'))

checkn()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are trying to access the `n` variable that is *locally scoped* to the `checkn` function. The easiest way to solve this, is for your `fermat` function to take an argument, and then in your `checkn` function, pass `n` to `fermat`.

Defining `fermat` to take an argument:

I changed the argument to be `x` just to help isolate the fact that the `n` variables are not the same. You are passing the value to the function.

```
def fermat(x):
    if (a**x) + (b**x) == (c**x):
        print('Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!')
    else:
        print("No, that doesn't work")
```

In the `checkn` function, pass `n` to `fermat` (relevant part shown only):

```
    else:
        fermat(n)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for that explanation. I see that I needed to pass the argument from within the function checkn() to fermat(). Is there a way to have the user input n and check to see that it is greater than 2 without defining a whole new function?

Comment: @ivan What you are doing is fine right now. It is all a matter of just changing the structure of your code. If you are looking to keep asking until the correct input, then you want to use a `while` loop. There are tons of examples on SO about that to help.

Comment: Ah, yes! I have to wait a few minutes before I can accept an answer. I'm assuming it's because I am still new :P Your help is greatly appreciated!! edit: ah yes, the while loop! Forgot I just learned that :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add for the sake of completion. (By restructuring your code, you do not have to pass any variable to the function call)

```
def fermat():
    N = powN;
    while N <= 2:
        N = int(input("Please enter pow > 2: \n"));
    if (a**N) + (b**N) == (c**N):
        print("Fermat is wrong my holy!!");
    else:
        print("That doesn't work");

a = int(input("Enter x: \n"));
b = int(input("Enter y: \n"));
c = int(input("Enter z: \n"));
powN = int(input("Enter pow: \n"));

fermat();
```

Comment: Ah, I get it! This makes total sense. Thank you!